# Ruby version differs from the rbenv one in server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, server, rbenv

I've read similar questions but still unlucky. In my server (Ubuntu 16.04) I have two user: `root` and `other`. I want to config a Rails project.

Now, after some configuration I installed the `v2.5` version of Ruby (required) as a `root` user using Rbenv, but in the `other` profile the version kept the same as default (`v2.3`).

I've managed to know set the proper version in the `other` profile. When I do:

```
rbenv versions
```

The output is the following:

> system
>
> * 2.5.0 (set by /home/other/.rbenv/version)

But when I do:

```
ruby -v
```

The version keeps being the default one:

> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

How to set the version to `v2.5`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question kinda answers itself, you have one Ruby installed as one user, and another Ruby version installed for another user. When you run as root, it will use the version installed for the root user, and when vice-versa. This is less of a Ruby question than a Linux question, as this is the default behavior. I found using RVM can simplify this process.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Not actually, if you check my description I've said that in the second user I've installed the required version (`v2.5`) but when checking using `ruby -v` it keeps showing the default one (`v2.3`)

Comment: What does `sudo ruby -v` say?

Comment: @ForeverZer0 again, is all in the description: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

Comment: No, actually doesn't say what `sudo ruby -v` says, only without the `sudo`.

Comment: Well, it is the same output in this case.

Comment: you have two ruby installed on you system, one by `apt install` and other with `rbenv`. if you need to have two or more versions you need to uninstall that installed by `apt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run ruby -v, it's considering your ruby installed by `apt install ruby`.

You must remove `ruby-build` with `apt remove ruby-build` and clone the `ruby-build` to inside `rbenv` directory and then install and set as global with rbenv.

I want to recommend you to read and follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04) after remove local ruby-build.

Comment: Yeah, I actually solve it yesterday but forgot to post and answer but this is solution. The only thing I did different was installing Ruby with RVM.

Comment: Hey @kenny Horna, how do you set the path in other server for rvm? Or you install rvm in both.

Comment: @KennyHorna did you need setup nvm also?

Comment: @Asterisk I'm sorry, this was long time ago, I don't remember properly if I needed to (but I doubt I needed to do any specific config since I'm not familiar with nvm).